# Vue computed property returns the whole function instead of the value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this computed prop:

```
methods: {
    url_refresh: function (id) {
        return `${this.url_base}?start=${Date.now()}`
    }
}
```

And when i try to console log on mount:

```
mounted() {
    console.log(this.url_refresh);
},
```

It logs the function instead of the value:

[image]

How do I get the value instead of the function?

Its supposed to return `http://localhost/admin/agenda/refresh?agenda_id=2&start=2020-11-29T00:00:00-03:00`

Comment: You don't call the function. Add the parenthesis and a value for id: `this.url_refresh(id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably use `methods` instead of `computed`, [look here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

Should Work for you (tested):

```
<template>
  <div>
    Your Template
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.url_refresh);
  },
  data() {
    return { url_base: "http://localhost/admin/agenda/refresh" };
  },
  computed: {
    url_refresh() {
      return `${this.url_base}?start=${Date.now()}`;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Will log: `http://localhost/admin/agenda/refresh?start=1607431794589`

Answer (score 0):

[Computed Caching vs Methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

Main point of using `computed` is caching behavior. Hence it doesn't make sense to pass any argument into computed (the result should depend only on other reactive data). If you need argument, use `methods` instead...